# Compiling iOS App in Release mode avoiding Tests building

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm having some strange issue with the way Xcode compile Swift for `Debug` and `Release`. It seems that there are some differences that let the App crash when compiled as `Release` that doesn't make that App crash if compiled as `Debug` (i.e. using a forced unwrap inside `UIView.animationdWithDuration` completion closure).

Due to this problem I'd like to build my application as `Release` before submitting it via testFlight or whatever to my testers. The problem that I've found is that I can't compile and run in Release mode if I have a `Test` target too. So I wonder how can I temporarily stop `Test` target building to build and run only the App in `Release` mode ?

Comment: not answering to your question... I had problems with my release swift app, and I solved them removing the compiler optimizations options from the project. (set them to none, the same as in debug) maybe this helps you with your errors.

Comment: this is probably caused by the optimization done in a release build. You should be able to set the optimization to the same for debug for your purpose - I wouldn't do as suggested above for the final release since without these optimization code will be often very slow.